# Flutter Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Tags: flutter

I'm using GETX.

Now I've updated my all code. Anything you need tell me. Kindly I want to solve this problem today as I'm stuck here from 2 weeks and I can't figure out what is the reason behind.

Thanks

**Registeration Code**

```
void _freelancerRegistration(AuthController authController) {
SignUpBody signUpBody = SignUpBody(
      name: name, email: email, password: password, phone: phone);
  authController.registration(signUpBody).then((status) {
    if (status.success!) {
      print('sucess');
    } else {
      Utils.flushBarErrorMessage(status.enMessage!, context);
    }
  });
}
```

This is body which I want to pass from SignUp.

**SignUpBody.dart**

```
   class SignUpBody {
  SignUpBody({
    String? name,
    String? email,
    String? password,
    String? phone,
  }) {
    _name = name;
    _email = email;
    _password = password;
    _phone = phone;
  }

  SignUpBody.fromJson(dynamic json) {
    _name = json['name'];
    _email = json['email'];
    _password = json['password'];
    _phone = json['phone'];
  }

  String? _name;
  String? _email;
  String? _password;
  String? _phone;

  SignUpBody copyWith({
    String? name,
    String? email,
    String? password,
    String? phone,
  }) =>
      SignUpBody(
        name: name ?? _name,
        email: email ?? _email,
        password: password ?? _password,
        phone: phone ?? _phone,
      );

  String? get name => _name;

  String? get email => _email;

  String? get password => _password;

  String? get phone => _phone;

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final map = <String, dynamic>{};
    map['name'] = _name;
    map['email'] = _email;
    map['password'] = _password;
    map['phone'] = _phone;
    return map;
  }
}
```

This the response I'm getting from Postman and then I've created its model.

**ResponseModel.dart**

```
class ResponseModel {
  ResponseModel({
    bool? success,
    String? enMessage,
    String? arMessage,
    Data? data,
    int? status,
  }) {
    _success = success;
    _enMessage = enMessage;
    _arMessage = arMessage;
    _data = data;
    _status = status;
  }

  ResponseModel.fromJson(dynamic json) {
    _success = json['success'];
    _enMessage = json['en_message'];
    _arMessage = json['ar_message'];
    _data = json['data'] != null ? Data.fromJson(json['data']) : null;
    _status = json['status'];
  }

  bool? _success;
  String? _enMessage;
  String? _arMessage;
  Data? _data;
  int? _status;

  ResponseModel copyWith({
    bool? success,
    String? enMessage,
    String? arMessage,
    Data? data,
    int? status,
  }) =>
      ResponseModel(
        success: success ?? _success,
        enMessage: enMessage ?? _enMessage,
        arMessage: arMessage ?? _arMessage,
        data: data ?? _data,
        status: status ?? _status,
      );

  bool? get success => _success;

  String? get enMessage => _enMessage;

  String? get arMessage => _arMessage;

  Data? get data => _data;

  int? get status => _status;

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final map = <String, dynamic>{};
    map['success'] = _success;
    map['en_message'] = _enMessage;
    map['ar_message'] = _arMessage;
    if (_data != null) {
      map['data'] = _data?.toJson();
    }
    map['status'] = _status;
    return map;
  }
}

/// user : {"first_name":"name","username":"","email":"xxff@gmail.com","type":1,"role_id":4,"verification_code":7257,"verified":0,"phone":"123456","updated_at":"2022-06-30T11:38:51.000000Z","created_at":"2022-06-30T11:38:51.000000Z","id":122,"balance":[{"AED":0}]}

class Data {
  Data({
    User? user,
  }) {
    _user = user;
  }

  Data.fromJson(dynamic json) {
    _user = json['user'] != null ? User.fromJson(json['user']) : null;
  }

  User? _user;

  Data copyWith({
    User? user,
  }) =>
      Data(
        user: user ?? _user,
      );

  User? get user => _user;

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final map = <String, dynamic>{};
    if (_user != null) {
      map['user'] = _user?.toJson();
    }
    return map;
  }
}

class User {
  User({
    String? firstName,
    String? username,
    String? email,
    int? type,
    int? roleId,
    int? verificationCode,
    int? verified,
    String? phone,
    String? updatedAt,
    String? createdAt,
    int? id,
    List<Balance>? balance,
  }) {
    _firstName = firstName;
    _username = username;
    _email = email;
    _type = type;
    _roleId = roleId;
    _verificationCode = verificationCode;
    _verified = verified;
    _phone = phone;
    _updatedAt = updatedAt;
    _createdAt = createdAt;
    _id = id;
    _balance = balance;
  }

  User.fromJson(dynamic json) {
    _firstName = json['first_name'];
    _username = json['username'];
    _email = json['email'];
    _type = json['type'];
    _roleId = json['role_id'];
    _verificationCode = json['verification_code'];
    _verified = json['verified'];
    _phone = json['phone'];
    _updatedAt = json['updated_at'];
    _createdAt = json['created_at'];
    _id = json['id'];
    if (json['balance'] != null) {
      _balance = [];
      json['balance'].forEach((v) {
        _balance?.add(Balance.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  String? _firstName;
  String? _username;
  String? _email;
  int? _type;
  int? _roleId;
  int? _verificationCode;
  int? _verified;
  String? _phone;
  String? _updatedAt;
  String? _createdAt;
  int? _id;
  List<Balance>? _balance;

  User copyWith({
    String? firstName,
    String? username,
    String? email,
    int? type,
    int? roleId,
    int? verificationCode,
    int? verified,
    String? phone,
    String? updatedAt,
    String? createdAt,
    int? id,
    List<Balance>? balance,
  }) =>
      User(
        firstName: firstName ?? _firstName,
        username: username ?? _username,
        email: email ?? _email,
        type: type ?? _type,
        roleId: roleId ?? _roleId,
        verificationCode: verificationCode ?? _verificationCode,
        verified: verified ?? _verified,
        phone: phone ?? _phone,
        updatedAt: updatedAt ?? _updatedAt,
        createdAt: createdAt ?? _createdAt,
        id: id ?? _id,
        balance: balance ?? _balance,
      );

  String? get firstName => _firstName;

  String? get username => _username;

  String? get email => _email;

  int? get type => _type;

  int? get roleId => _roleId;

  int? get verificationCode => _verificationCode;

  int? get verified => _verified;

  String? get phone => _phone;

  String? get updatedAt => _updatedAt;

  String? get createdAt => _createdAt;

  int? get id => _id;

  List<Balance>? get balance => _balance;

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final map = <String, dynamic>{};
    map['first_name'] = _firstName;
    map['username'] = _username;
    map['email'] = _email;
    map['type'] = _type;
    map['role_id'] = _roleId;
    map['verification_code'] = _verificationCode;
    map['verified'] = _verified;
    map['phone'] = _phone;
    map['updated_at'] = _updatedAt;
    map['created_at'] = _createdAt;
    map['id'] = _id;
    if (_balance != null) {
      map['balance'] = _balance?.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return map;
  }
}

/// AED : 0

class Balance {
  Balance({
    int? aed,
  }) {
    _aed = aed;
  }

  Balance.fromJson(dynamic json) {
    _aed = json['AED'];
  }

  int? _aed;

  Balance copyWith({
    int? aed,
  }) =>
      Balance(
        aed: aed ?? _aed,
      );

  int? get aed => _aed;

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final map = <String, dynamic>{};
    map['AED'] = _aed;
    return map;
  }
}
```

**AuthController.dart**

```
class AuthController extends GetxController implements GetxService {
  final AuthRepo authRepo;

  AuthController({required this.authRepo});

  bool _isLoading = false;

  bool get isLoading => _isLoading;

  Future<ResponseModel> registration(SignUpBody signUpBody) async {
    _isLoading = true;
    update();
    Response response = await authRepo.registration(signUpBody);
    late ResponseModel responseModel;
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      authRepo.saveUserToken(response.body["token"]);
      responseModel =
          ResponseModel(success: true, enMessage: response.body['token']);
    } else {
      responseModel =
          ResponseModel(success: false, enMessage: response.statusText);
    }
    _isLoading = false;
    update();
    return responseModel;
  }

  Future<ResponseModel> login(String email, String password) async {
    print('Getting Token');
    print(authRepo.getUserToken().toString());
    _isLoading = true;
    update();
    Response response = await authRepo.login(email, password);
    late ResponseModel responseModel;
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print('Backend Token');
      authRepo.saveUserToken(response.body["token"]);
      print(response.body['token'].toString());

      responseModel =
          ResponseModel(success: true, enMessage: response.body["token"]);
    } else {
      responseModel =
          ResponseModel(success: false, enMessage: response.statusText!);
    }
    _isLoading = false;
    update();
    return responseModel;
  }
}
```

**AuthRepo.dart**

```
   class AuthRepo {
  final ApiClient apiClient;
  final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

  AuthRepo({required this.apiClient, required this.sharedPreferences});

  Future<Response> registration(SignUpBody signUpBody) async {
    return await apiClient.postData(
        AppConstants.REGISTRATION_URI, signUpBody.toJson());
  }

  Future<bool> saveUserToken(String token) async {
    apiClient.token = token;
    apiClient.updateHeader(token);
    return await sharedPreferences.setString(AppConstants.TOKEN, token);
  }

  Future<Response> login(String email, String password) async {
    return await apiClient.postData(
        AppConstants.LOGIN_URI, {"email": email, "password": password});
  }

  Future<String> getUserToken()async{
    return sharedPreferences.getString(AppConstants.TOKEN)??"";
  }
}
```

**ApiClient.dart**

```
class ApiClient extends GetConnect implements GetxService {
  late String token;
  final String appBaseUrl;

  late SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
  late Map<String, String> _mainHeaders;

  ApiClient({required this.appBaseUrl, required this.sharedPreferences}) {
    baseUrl = appBaseUrl;
    timeout = const Duration(seconds: 30);
    token = sharedPreferences.getString(AppConstants.TOKEN) ?? "";
    _mainHeaders = {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
    };
  }
  void updateHeader(String token) {
    _mainHeaders = {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
    };
  }

  Future<Response> postData(String uri, dynamic body) async {
    print(body.toString());
    try {
      Response response = await post(uri, body, headers: _mainHeaders);
      print(response.toString());

      return response;
    } catch (e) {
      return Response(statusCode: 1, statusText: e.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your `saveUserToken` is difficult to say, but it seems that `response.body["token"]` is `null` and since `saveUserToken` will be something like `saveUserToken(String token) { ... }`, Dart is raising a type error.

I suggest you to check if your token is null or not and then throwing manually if it is. Something like this:

```
Future < ResponseModel > registration(SignUpBody signUpBody) async {
    _isLoading = true;
    update();
    // no need of "late" here, you are function scoped
    ResponseModel responseModel;
    Response response;

    try {
        response = await authRepo.registration(signUpBody);
        final String token = response.body["token"];

        if (response.statusCode == 200 && token != null) {
            await authRepo.saveUserToken();
            responseModel = ResponseModel(success: true, enMessage: response.body['token']);
        } else {
           throw new Error('A custom message');
        }
    } on Error catch (e) {
        print(e);
        responseModel = ResponseModel(success: false, enMessage: response.statusText);
    } finally {
        _isLoading = false;
        update();
    }

    return responseModel;
}
```

Comment: I've updated and added `saveusertoken`

Comment: In fact your `saveUserToken` function wants a non-nullable String, so my answer was correct.

Comment: A tip: you should `await` that function, as it's async

Comment: Hi brother, I've updated my question. I'm getting some issue. Please take a look. Where I've to use `await`?

Comment: Also there is a warning on `if (response.statusCode == 200 && token != null)` as The operand can't be null, so the condition is always true. Remove the condition.

Comment: Yes, my bad, I did a syntax error. I've update my code now. Give it a try

Comment: I also put the await where you asked

Comment: error I'm facing now `on Error catch (e) {
      print(e);
      responseModel = ResponseModel(success: false, enMessage: response.statusText);
    }` Undefined name 'response'.

Comment: Updated again! Sorry, but without compiling it it's extremely difficult to avoid those mistakes :D

Comment: same issue, as I've already tried this.

Comment: error on `return responseModel;` The non-nullable local variable 'responseModel' must be assigned before it can be used. (Documentation)  Try giving it an initializer expression, or ensure that it's assigned on every execution path.

Comment: So I'm not sure if my comment on removing the `late` keyword was correct. Try to put `late` in front of ResponseModel and Response

Comment: I've commented that line but still I'm getting same issue `type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'`

Comment: could you please update your code?

Comment: Hi now I've updated All my code.

Comment: Are you checking Code?

Answer (score 0):

Check if `response.body["token"]` is really not null. You can output the variable via console. Otherwise send the whole error message. It is certainly not only one single line long.

Comment: English only here, please

Comment: downvote removed :D

Comment: `response.body["token"]` is null. how to resolve it.